# Trouble Positioning Text Over An Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-position

After following an excellent tutorial that I found on Stack Overflow and of which can be seen here: http://fearlessflyer.com/2012/12/how-to-create-a-jquery-image-rotator/

I created my own that can be seen here; http://www.your-adrenaline-fix.com/

My trouble is that I am having trouble with the h2 text.

1. When the page first loads you'll briefly see a jumbled mess of all the h2's. I have no idea where to begin on this one and if anyone wouldn't mind commenting on how I could correct this I'd be most appreciative.
2. If I position the text so that the single line text sits just above the bottom of each image, when the script gets to the image's with 2 lines of text, the 2nd line is now well below the image in a way that looks horrible yet I experimented with this for atleast a good couple hours and I can't seem to get the text to simply display near the bottom of each image regardless of the number of lines of text.

I have only provided the css that I feel is appropriate, however, should you need more, feel free to review the source of my page here; view-source:http://www.your-adrenaline-fix.com/ or ask and I'll gladly share.

```
#featured h2 {
    border:none;
    font-size:41px;
    font-family:Helvetica;
    color:#fff;
    padding:5px;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    top:310px;
    text-shadow:1px 3px 2px #000;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:-1px;
    width:450px;
}
```

I thank each of you in advance,
Stuart K

Comment: For the display issue when loading the page. You could hide the h2 first using js/jquery then make them appear again after the page is loaded. For positioning the text, you are using top:xxx use bottom xxx and your problem will be solved

Comment: _"I have only provided the css that I feel is appropriate, should you need more, feel free to review the source of my page"_ Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. See [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/)

Comment: @j08691 My appologies. Regarding adding meaningful code, I thought I was. The css. I provided a link so that people here can "See What I'm Talking About"

Comment: @Huangism Could you kindly share with me how I may accomplish such a feat with js/jquery? I'm sorry but I am in WAY over my head and your assistance will truly be appreciated.

Comment: @YourAdrenalineFix Honestly, I wouldn't worry about the initial jump. If you have a faster connection it might not jump at all. I don't think posting the jquery you need will help you, it's basically just giving you code which you don't know why it works. You can look up http://jquery.com/. If you don't know any JS then this might not be a good idea

Comment: @Huangism I tried bottom:20px; and now the text is so far outside the image box, it's not even part of it

Comment: @Huangism Honestly, I've been through SO many, HTML, CSS, PHP, AJAX and MySQL (as well as those Im forgetting) tutorials over the past year, YOU'D be impressed. Now I'm actually moving into jQuery and JS and in a few months I'll be dangerous so "Giving Me" the code is actually NOT as bad as you make it sound because I'm the one who will discect it and figure out how it all works so sharing the code and getting me up & running would be very much appreciated. (At this point Im Hoping for a 1 liner??)

Comment: @YourAdrenalineFix it seems your slide show is setup differently then I anticipated. It will take awhile to update the answer.

Comment: @YourAdrenalineFix The answer is updated, if you don't have firebug, you should grab that, it is a powerful debugging tool

Answer (score 0):

You have your text position from the top, which is why it goes beyond the image, you need to position the text from the bottom so it won't go beyond

something like

```
#featured h2 {
    bottom: 20px;
    // remove top property
}
```

I only replaced the top part with bottom and edited the pixel amount. You can adjust it as needed from here.

For the display issue when loading the page. You could hide the h2 first using js/jquery then make them appear again after the page is loaded.

Here is the basic structure, I leave the coding to you since I am not sure how well you know /jsjquery

1) in your css, hide the h2 tags, this does not requires js

2) on window load (so the images are loaded), show the h2 tags

```
$(window).load(function() {
     // show desired content now
     // you could do transitions here but I will leave that up to you to figure out
     $('#featured .container h2').show(); 
});
```

Update

You need to setup the slideshow a bit differently in the css, it does not work right now because everything in your content container is positioned absolutely, meaning it is removed from the normal flow. This gives your content containers a height of 0, which is why your text is above the container. What I have done is making the images not absolute so this gives your container a height, and apply display none to hide them, because we don't want to see them all at once. Since your scripts marks the currently shown container with the class .current. We just need to target that img to show. With the container having a height the position of the text is now set 20px from the bottom of the container, in this case the bottom of the image because the image is all we have in the container

```
// only the current slide image will show up
#featured div.container.current img {
    display: block;
}
// remove position absolute and hide the images
#featured div.container img {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; // remove this line
}
```

Update :

for the h2 tag, in your css do

```
visibility: hidden;
```

and then add

```
#featured div.container.current h2 {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

this way the text is hidden until you hit the current image, see if this works

Comment: Please give me a while to process all of this but I have to say that I did replace top:310px; with bottom:20px; just as you did but with this configuration the text is above the image

Comment: And HUGE Thanks for this. I'm going to be leaving for about a half hr but when I return I will peruse this and will likely have addtl questions but I Thank You Immensely for your help!!

Comment: The css positioning part is fairly basic and so is the jquery part. Good luck

Comment: And resonses like: "1) in your css, hide the h2 tags, this does not requires js" are PERFECT and most appreciated

Comment: I think I've got it just about functional but now if you review the link I provided above, you'll see the h2 text briefly appear above the image before falling into place near the bottom of the image. If you wouldn't mind helping me out on this last bit, again. I'd be most appreciative.

Comment: Is $('#featured .container h2').show(); not in the correct place?

Comment: Sorry, I was away again. Ofcourse I'd let you know if it works. Now lemme give it a go

Comment: I hope I placed everything correctly as I tried to do so in a hurry but now I get NO h2 text.

Comment: BTW, Once I get this ironed out I WILL be re-reviewing everything in an attempt to better understand what's happening.

Comment: Please make sure you put in the second part of the css with the .current, that makes the text show when it is on the current slide. You can edit and add to your previous comment if you wrote it not too long ago, no need to make more comments. On my bad, change the second part img to h2, just updated the typo

Comment: Im sorry but I don't understand at all what you just wrote

Comment: I edited the last part of my answer, #featured div.container.current h2 used to be #featured div.container.current img, that was my mistake

Comment: Oh... So sorry I wasn't able to interpret that. My bad. My head is just spinning and now I'll be going back over all of it (jQuery slider as a whole) cleaning up where I can etc. Thank You So Much For Your Help!! PS, I've written this entire site from scratch but I still have trouble with complex statements such as;  #featured div.container.current h2... Go figure huh??